# Привязка двух таблиц через масивы

Tags: jquery, массивы, html, css

Есть две таблицы. Высота соответствующих ячеек должна быть одинаковой (если в правой таблицы текст розтянул высоту ячейки, то в левой соответствующая ячейка должна принять аналогичную высоту )

```
 <table class="table-left">
  <tr>
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <table class="table-right">
  <tr>
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

построял два масива:
       один из набора высот tr правой таблицы:

```
    var rows_right =  $(".table-right tr").map(function(){
    return $(this).height();
}).get();
```

второй масив из набора td левой таблицы (в левой будеть только одна ячейка td для каждого tr)

```
var rows_left = $(".table-left td").map(function(){
    return $(this);
}).get();
```

Теперь нужно связать как-то два масива. То есть, чтобы значения масива rows_right принимали соответвующие элементы второго масива rows_left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё вроде бы ясно, но одно понять не могу - зачем вам стро**И**ть какие-то массивы?
Смотрите [такой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tu7CJ/2/).

```
var rTr = $('.table-right tr');
$('.table-left tr').each(function(i, el){
    rTr.eq(i).find('td').height($('td',el).height());
});
```